# Office.js: How can I debug ExecuteFunction commands

Tags: office-js, office-2016

I have a command button on a custom ribbon in Excel with an action of type ExecuteFunction which calls a global javascript function in a function file I point to.

Everything works as expected when running things locally, but when I run the same code on a remote server, nothing happens.

When I go to the remote url of my function file in Internet Explorer, and call the function from the console, it also works as expected.

There is something about my remote server that only Excel doesn't seem to like. Perhaps related to bad certs?

Since this code isn't running in a taskpane, no IE process shows up in the F12 tools where I normally go to debug.

**How can I debug this function when it gets called from inside Excel?**

Comment: Hey, I'm having the same question, did you find a solution ?